# jQuery animate border-bottom-width

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate, border

I want to animate the border-bottom-width from 10px to 0px, how can I do that?

```
$(".shortener:last").animate({
        'borderBottomWidth' : '0px'});
```

That doesn't work, thanks!.

**UPDATE**: I used margin-bottom: -10px

Comment: oops.. i fear you cant do that :( http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7085

Comment: Look into [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/). No guarantee, but it allows for more animations on styles.

Comment: @prasann - that bug report was closed as invalid. I just created a jsFiddle that shows the bottom border width animating just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to work fine in this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/uvwa8/)**:

jQuery:

```
  $("#block").animate({
    borderBottomWidth: "0px"
  }, 1500 );
```

CSS:

```
div {
width:100px;
border:10px solid green;
}​
```

HTML:

```
<button id="go">&raquo; Run</button>
<div id="block">Hello!</div>​
```

Note the property values being animated don't need quotes like you used in your example.

Comment: Also, do you know how to select divs that contain *WORD* in ID vía CSS? +1 Button adds iframes with ID "___plusone_1", the last name increases on each button and I want to apply a CSS Rule for all *plusone* tags. Thanks

Comment: If it works in the jsFiddle but not one your site, you may have other code (CSS, jQuery, JavaScript) that may be conflicting. To answer your second question, `$("[id*="+text+"]")` should work.